# Is release needed for a reference turned from retain on autorelease object?

Tags: objective-c, release, retain, autorelease

For the following code, 1 - is retain needed on the object returned back from getFoo; 2 - is the release needed on foo in method func?

```
- (NSString *)getFoo {
    return [[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"foo"] autorelease];
}

- (void)func {
    // ??? is the retain needed?
    NSString *foo = [[self getFoo] retain];

    // use foo

    // ??? is the release needed?
    [foo release];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `retain` must be match with a `release`.

This said, in your func you don't need to `retain` *foo if you are not delaying it's use.
Usually autorelease pool get's `drain` at the end of the run loop so you have the time to use it locally in your function.
But if you `retain` you must `release`.

And you could do this :

```
return [NSString stringWithString:@"foo];
```

This is a convenience methode that return an `autorelease` object to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you `alloc`, `copy` or `retain` an object you need to `release` it.

In your example, you don't need to retain it. But since you did, you do need to release it.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've written is fine.
When you alloc the string it's retain count is 1.
You then autorelease the string which will decrement the retain count at a later time.
You use foo.
Then you don't need to release it since you already autoreleased it: it will automatically be released later.

Note that you could use stringWithFormat or stringWithString to create a string that is already autoreleased.

This would be a bit neater.